# XCode 6 autocomplete stopped working

Tags: xcode

XCode 6 Beta 5 and autocomplete stopped working. I thought problem in Beta 5 but I've reinstall to Beta 4 and it's still not work but it did before. I check preferences for "suggests" and I tried to delete Derived Data but it doesn't help

Comment: Is it in all files? If the file isn't correctly added to compile sources it can cause issues like autocomplete stop working etc. I've got the same issue for multiple versions of xcode and it usually turns out to be something like that.

Comment: I've no delete no add any files

Comment: I got that this problem with my current project. With other works good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Problem was in an array.
I have big array like: 
`let array:[NSString] = ["first","second"...]`
 I changed it to 
`var array = ["first","second"...]`
I don't why it's happened but it works. It was so hard to find the problem.

Answer (score 12):

1. Clear derived data.
2. Under build settings, select Always Search User Paths to "YES".
3. Clean the project.

Comment: Can you please explain how to "Clear derived data". This is very vague

Comment: In the main menu for xcode go to 'Window'->'Organizer'. Select the 'Projects' tab and select your project from the list on the left. You should see a section there with the location of your derived data and snapshots and a 'delete' button for each. Clicking on the 'delete' button for derived data should clear it.

Comment: Delete entire folder: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: @VanDuTran - I know, it's irritating. Trying Cmd+K (clean project) works for me most of the times. Else, terminate Xcode, and then clear derived data folder. Now relaunch Xcode. If that doesn't work, file a bug with Apple, though it's a beta, so it might be an existing bug. Check the release notes.

Comment: @GautamJain I somehow managed to fix the problem.. magically :)

Comment: clearing derived data and restarting Xcode and waiting for indexing to finish is all I needed to do

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me recently because I had a /* */ style comment after the @end of my @implementation.

Not sure why that would break autocomplete but moving the comment into the implementation fixed autocomplete.

There seems to be a lot of reasons autocomplete breaks. Just adding to the list..

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem.

This is what worked for me.

1. Clear derived data.

Window -> Organizer -> "Select you project" -> Delete Derived Data.

2. Clean the project
3. Quit Xcode ----- this is very important. You might have to restart you computer.
4. Open Xcode again

Hope this works for you. This worked on 2/9/2015

Comment: This have been attempted and did not work!
Please read the question before suggesting.

Comment: @thedp .... Did you look at the date = 2/9/2015. Things are not always going to work on Different versions of Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the .m file has been checked in "Target Membership"

Answer (score 0):

Tried to clean/delete derived data multiple times. Autocomplete was disabled in some files, but not App Delegate.  After a while I saw red libraries int he project navigator. Those are managed by cocoapods. The solution turned out to be:

- Navigate to the project root folder
- Delete "Pods" directory
- open terminal, type cd
- drag the project folder there to get full path
- run pod install

Upon reinstalling pods, syntax highlighting and code completion is restored in the affected files.

Comment: Who said anything about pods?

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because it was a new problem since upgrading my version of Xcode.  After downloading the documentation again, everything worked fine.